# If specific class has included, add class to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want to add a class to parent div (**.main**) if **.option-not-available** included in dl.

I tried with this way but it's not adding class to parent. Please a take a look at below.

```
<div class="main">
 <dl>
   <dt>Coffee</dt>
   <dd class="option-not-available">Black hot drink</dd>
  </dl>
<div>

if ($('dd').hasClass('option-not-available')) {
   $(this).parent().addClass('active');
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: @J. Meijer - I was just adding a comment to your answer that you were correct about `this` .. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `this` is not a reference to the `dd` element in the `if` statement and the `parent()` of the `dd` is the `dl`, so that logic isn't quite right.

The simplest way to achieve this would be to select the `dd` by the `.option-not-available` class, then find the parent `.main` and apply `.active` on that:

```js
$('dd.option-not-available').closest('.main').addClass('active');
```

```css
.active { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <dl>
    <dt>Coffee</dt>
    <dd class="option-not-available">Black hot drink</dd>
  </dl>
<div>
```

Comment: I believe `$(this).closest('dl')` would also work?Also please elaborate `Note that this is not a reference to the dd element` a little more.If it is not referring to dd then what else does it refers to here?

Comment: The OP states `I just want to add a class to parent div (.main)`, not the closest `dl`. JS only has function scope, hence the logic within `if` is at the scope of the parent container. There is no indication of what the would be in the OP's example. However, assuming this logic is executed at the highest level within a `document.ready` handler, `this` would refer to the `window`.

Comment: given the current DOM,`.closest()` would also give the parent dd.Im not berating in any sense here just wanted to understand how would `$(this).closest('dl')` work(if it does) if this is not referencing to the element?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you're referring to my code, I'm not using `this`. If you're referring to the OPs code, then `this` will not work.

Comment: I read a solution to a similar problem here on SO where using `$(this).closest('...')` was suggested I m trying to understand if `this` is not referring to that particular element how does it finds its closest element?

Comment: I think you're confusing yourself here. Without seeing the context of the code you're talking about it's hard to understand what you mean. If you specifically want to know how `closest()` works, it traverses up the DOM through each element's `parentNode` property, checking if the given element matches the selector you provided. You can see the implementation of this in the [source](https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=2.1.3&fn=jQuery.fn.closest)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the class name to the selector :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('dd.option-not-available').each(function(){
         $(this).closest('div.main').addClass('active');     
    });
});
```

```css
.active {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <dl>
    <dt>Coffee</dt>
    <dd class="option-not-available">Black hot drink</dd>
  </dl>
<div>
```